# Angular ng-click scope undefined function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code generated by laravel partial view...

```
<div ng-controller="viajeController">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#/">Volver</a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h3>Horario de Salida:</h3> 
        <select class="form-control" name="sel_horario" ng-model="hora" ng-options="hora.hora_inicio for hora in horarios | orderBy: 'id'" id="sel_horario" ></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">          

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Asignar Vehiculo </legend>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>Seleccione</th>
                    <th>Placa</th>
                    <th>Numero Interno</th>
                    <th>Tipo Vehiculo</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="vehiculo in vehiculos">
                        <td>
                            <a href="" ng-click="solicitaDespacho(<% vehiculo.id %>)">Seleccionar</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><% vehiculo.placa %></td>
                        <td><% vehiculo.numero_interno %></td>
                        <td><% vehiculo.tipo_vehiculo %></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

all under the controller "viajeController" this is the code:

```
app.controller('viajeController',function ($scope, $location, viajeFactory){

$scope.horarios = viajeFactory.horarios;
viajeFactory.async().then(function(d){
    $scope.vehiculos = d;
});

$scope.solicitaDespacho = function(idVeh){
    var urlPost = '/asignarVehiculo';
    var idHora = $("#sel_horario").val();

    if (idHora != 'undefined' && idHora != '?'){
        urlPost = '/addViajeData/'+idVeh;   
    }else{
        alert('Debe seleccionar un horario de salida.');
    }

    $location.path(urlPost);

};
});
```

viajeFactory is OK, but when I click on `<a href="" ng-click="solicitaDespacho(<% vehiculo.id %>)">Seleccionar</a>` put a error in console:

undefined is not a function

Why not found a "solicitaDespacho" function on $scope??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
<a href="" ng-click="solicitaDespacho(<% vehiculo.id %>)">Seleccionar</a>
```

to

```
 <a href="" ng-click="solicitaDespacho(vehiculo.id)">Seleccionar</a>
```

Comment: Also, you did not include enough HTML to verify that you are actually attaching your controller to the DOM properly. Make sure you have an ngController directive somewhere in your HTML above this ngRepeat that actually _uses_ viajeController in the first place!

Comment: sorry I dont't say I change {{ for <% because I use laravel with blade, so ng-repeat generate a good html solicitaDespacho(1), solicitaDespacho(2).. etc, but when I click say undefined

Comment: works but with ng-click="solicitaDespacho(vehiculo.id)" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ; after the closing bracket of the function.